# VIM: How can I search match a line which doesn't have a particular character?

Tags: search, vim, design-patterns, vi, text-mining

I have some lines like this from an ldiff file,

```
dn: cn=dkalland_directs_ww,cn=org_groups,cn=beehive_groups,cn=groups,dc=oracle
,dc=com
businesscategory: open
cn: dkalland_directs_ww
description: Directs Group for daniel.kallander@oracle.com
displayname: dkalland_directs_ww
mail: dkalland_directs_ww@oracle.com
objectclass: top
objectclass: orclGroup
objectclass: groupOfUniqueNames
orclglobalid: modified
orclnormdn: cn=dkalland_directs_ww,cn=org_groups,cn=beehive_groups,cn=groups,d
c=oracle,dc=com
owner: cn=BHGRPADMIN_WW,L=AMER,DC=ORACLE,DC=COM
uniquemember: cn=mattias_tobiasson,dc=us,dc=oracle,dc=com
uniquemember: cn=mattias_joelson,dc=us,dc=oracle,dc=com
uniquemember: cn=markus_persson,dc=us,dc=oracle,dc=com 
...
```

Now as there are some lines which are continuation of the previous line. I want to join them back to their respective line.

What I am confused about is how can I search a line without the `":"` character so that I can join it with previous line.

Plz help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you want to do a

```
:v/:/-1j
```

The `v` command selects all lines that *don't* match the patterh `/:/`. The `-1` selects the lines one above. and the `j` joins this line with the next line (i.e. the one selected with the `v` command)

**Edit** Benoit and dash-tom-bang have provided substantial improvements in their comments: the `1` is not necessary, since it is the default, and the `!` does not join the lines with a space. So, this leads to the following, better version:

```
:v/:/-j!
```

Comment: Note that the `1` is not mandatory: `:v/:/-j` also works. `1` is the default count when `+` and `-` unary operators for ranges are used.

Comment: I'd add an `!` to the end, too, so you don't get spaces added or removed at the point of the join.  (i.e. `:v/:/-j!`)

Comment: In fact with this approach I don't need to worry about macro and how many times I need to run it.... :D

Answer (score 4):

Pattern

```
^[^:]*$
```

matches lines without `:`, it can be useful in more common tasks when `:v` command is not suitable (a macro or some comparison in script)

Comment: With the above approach (using :v) I even don't need to worry about macro and it's counts :)